# A counting problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns user_id, time_stamp and activity which I use for recoding user actions for an audit trail.

How can I COUNT the number of unique user_id where time_stamp=0  when there might be multiple such rows, differing only in in the activity text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use:

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id)
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE t.time_stamp = 0
GROUP BY t.activity
```

Comment: @Mawg: The `GROUP BY` provides context for the aggregate function (`COUNT` in this example), otherwise the count would be for all records in the table.

Comment: I don't think that actually works.  Grouping by activities means that for each unique activity you get a count of distinct users. Drop the group by, and it'll work.

Comment: @jmoreno: Quoting the OP "COUNT the number of unique user_id where time_stamp=0 when there might be multiple such rows, differing only in in the activity text".  That means grouping by the activity column.

Comment: I'm reading the "when there might be multiple such rows" as being the problem he doesn't know how to overcome, thus my comment.  OTOH, he's accepted your answer, so maybe I am misreading...

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) 
FROM (select t.user_id, count(*) actions
      FROM table t
      where t.time_stamp = 0
      group by t.user_id) u
```

Should do it for you (not the most straightforward way, but it shows how to do a couple of different things).